# Slope keeps flowing when resize the browser (used clip-path)

Tags: html, css, mask, clip-path

I make the mask that has a slope, covers a half of the screen.

But when I resize the browser the slope part flows to the left side & angle changes like this.

Here’s the difference.

// Before resize

[image]

// After resize

[image]

```css
#home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
#home:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  clip-path: polygon(calc(80% - 6vw) 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, calc(60% - 6vw) 100%); 
}

#home-image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div id="home-image">
    <img src="img/background.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="home-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>PAGES</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

(I removed the menu part because the code went too long.)

Is there any solutions to stop flowing/collapsing angle against resize the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you may have forgotten to add a link to the CodePen.

Comment: can you hightlight the difference? not able to see .... and also post all the code with the question don't link to codepen

Comment: @AaronMcGuire TemaniAfif Edited my question. Added CODEPEN link and highlighted the images.

Comment: and we are far from having all the code in the question ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Did I miss something?

Comment: all the code need to be inside the question, don't use a codepen link .. you can change you codepen code at any time making the question irrelevant, so add all the needed code within the question so we don't need to open the codepen link

Comment: @TemaniAfif Edited again. Added the code instead of CODEPEN link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `clip-path` you can consider a background where you will use gradient. You will have a better support and you can keep the angle the same:

```css
#home {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
#home:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left:0;
  background: 
     linear-gradient(120deg,transparent 49.9%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 50%) center right/80% 300%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#home-image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div id="home-image">
    <img src="img/background.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="home-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>PAGES</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```